# Send celery task message to rabbitmq

Tags: python, django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I usually use celery with Django and run shared tasks in Django.

But for specific case, I want to add task queue to rabbitmq manually without running Django or celerybeat.

Is there any simple python script or shell cmd to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`send_task` method](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task) to queue a task to  an arbitrary celery broker.  But, you do have to know the app name and broker url so that you can send the task to the right place.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('app_name', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')
app.send_task('namespace.my_task', kwargs={
    'arg1': 'value1',
    'arg2': 'value2',
})
```

Comment: Ah. nice solution. I'll try it and let you know the result.